# Can a player touch the line while the ball is landing - Outdoor Volleyball (Beach or Grass)

Tags: rules, beach-volleyball

Scenario: The ball is heading towards a boundary line and the player is chasing it down.

The player contacts the line boundary line and the line moves at the same time the ball lands. Typical example, they step on the line.

Is the ball in or out (or replay point?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For FIVB Beach Volleyball, this is covered by 5.1.5 in the [2022 Casebook](https://www.fivb.com/-/media/2022/coorporate/beach%20volleyball/forms/refereeing%20forms/refereeing%20page/beach%20volleyball%20casebook%202022%20%20updated%20feb%202022.pdf?la=en&hash=8255AC57BE1B885236B9E509CC5CEBC3):

> What should the referee do if a ball landed inside the
> line, but obviously the line had been displaced
> substantially during a previous defending action?
>
> The 1st Referee should have the line corrected, and
> then call the ball “in” or “out”, depending on where
> the ball landed.

If the 1st Referee is unable to make a clear decision as to whether the ball was in or out, the rally should be replayed as it would for any other situation where the 1st Referee is unsure as to the correct judgement.

This obvious works a lot better on sand where the ball is likely to leave a clear mark than it does on grass; however as there are no professional level tournaments played on grass "nobody cares".